# How to validate documentation comment tags as part of the build

Tags: c#, msbuild, documentation-generation

We write documentation tags as part of our development process. It would be very useful being able to validate these code tags when building and having schema violations come up as warnings. Is it possible? And if so, what is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you output the documentation XML from at least one of your configurations when building. That will automatically enforce documentation schema validation. In project properties you will find a build tab where you will be able to specify xml documentation output.

Comment: This works great except it also warns when any public type or member is missing an XML comment, unless you ignore warning 1591 per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982525/visual-studio-disabling-missing-xml-comment-warning).

Answer (score 0):

FXCop (aka VSTS code analysis) has some rules that provide additional validation of XML comment integrity.

Comment: The current implementation of Code Analysis (VS 2013) does not seem to support this.