# Can I disable some C# compiler warning globally and enable it per file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

My problem is following: I have huge C# project with [1591](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591) disabled globally in the `.csproj` file.

`<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>`

However, I need to enable this warning in some files (some things MUST have xml comments).

I tried with `#pragma warning restore 1591` at the top of the C# file, but it does not work. The warning is ignored.

Can I disable some C# compiler warning globally and enable it per file?

I don't want to enable this warning per entire project (6908 warnings).

Comment: Looks like this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444631/how-to-disable-a-particular-compiler-warning-for-a-particular-file?rq=1
This link asks a question that is the inverse of yours.

Comment: Hi @CJohnson you are right, however, it does not work in my case (enabling rules globally and disabling per file is possible, the opposite seems to be not)

Comment: You can enable and disable warnings with C++, but not c#. I have never seen that with C# before.