# Disable IntelliSense warning on xml config file in .NetFramework project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, config, intellisense

I'm working with VisualStudio 2019, on a .NET FrameWork 4.7.2 project.
The project contains an xml config file (with .config ending).

I'm getting an IntelliSense warning on this file, and I would like to either suppress this specific warning, or to suppress all warnings for this file.

[image]

Example for a config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigExample>
</ConfigExample>
```

[image]

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982525/visual-studio-disabling-missing-xml-comment-warning

Comment: Thanks, in my case it wasn't relevant because I don't have a warning number, and because it's an IntelliSense warning

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following step:

**1)** first,open our config file on the code editor and then click menu **XML**-->**Create Schema**

[image]

**Then**, save the `App11.xsd` file into a folder.

**2)** click **XML**-->**Schemas**--> and click **Use this schemas** for your that file.

[image]

**3)** close your project and then reopen your project to enable that file.

**Besides**, if you have defined multiple elements, you can first write the elements on the config file, then Click **Create Schema** then creates a total XSD file.

Comment: Thanks Perry!
This is was just a dummy-example from my side to generate a warning on purpose tough, I would like to suppress it somehow (not resolve it)

Comment: To suppress it, you can try my suggestions and if you want them back, you can click do not use it under the custom `xxx.xsd` file under `XML`-->`Schemas`.

Comment: If my answer helps you understand and handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it.