# how to disable "missing xml comment..." warning?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, visual-studio-2022

I add swagger to my asp.net project. there are a lot of warnings

the warning code is blank. so I cannot disable it through [1591](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982525/visual-studio-disabling-missing-xml-comment-warning). please help me

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Disabling Missing XML Comment Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982525/visual-studio-disabling-missing-xml-comment-warning)

Comment: that warning has code 1591.  but my warning code is blank

Comment: Either document the methods (surely the whole reason you're pulling in swagger, no?) or change the accessibility of classes/methods that have been declared public and should not have been. Both of those sound more sensible than turning on documentation and then trying to suppress warnings about a lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your code this line to suppress the warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable "XML documentation file"

Comment: if so , how can i properly use swagger?  it require XML to pretty api document on swagger UI

Comment: All public functions must have a XML. Check if these functions have to be public.